# Leanback custom animation

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

How change animation speed(and delay) of zoomIn and zoomOut for items / rows? If possible in styles.

Also How change objectanimator/anim.xml for rows / items.

Comment: You can check out here in the [documentation to enlarge a view using a zoom animation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom). For additional reference, you can also check the public class [`ValueAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator).

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 i cant find any setters(xml or object) for BrowseSupportFragment.